# In C# what is the DateTime Format of a DateTimeOffset value: "2019-01-31T17:32:00-05:00"?

Tags: c#, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

In my C# code I am working with `DateTimeOffset?` values that I need to validate are in a given format. Here is an example value: `2019-01-31T17:32:00-05:00`. The part ending in "-05:00" will vary depending on if Daylight Savings Time is in effect or not (I am working with values in Eastern Time Zone). I need to be able to parse the `DateTimeOffset?` values and check if they are in a certain format matching the example value I gave earlier. This is my first time trying to parse dates formatted as `2019-01-31T17:32:00-05:00` so I'm not sure what datetime format I'm supposed to be using. Can someone assist with me finding the format please?

Comment: do you want to get the timezone out of a specific format?

Comment: so you are getting a string and want to parse it to a DateTimeOffset??  I think it is better you show your code and what is happening now and what you want to happen.